# Development server not showing web page in my default browser?

Tags: asp.net, windows-7

I installed windows 7 recently & I am new to ASP.NET.
I installed visual studio 2008 for developing ASP.NET application.

When I run my application, ASP.NET development server runs & my default browser opens automatically but doesn't show my web page.

A connection error occurs. Opening the web page with visual studio's internal browser works fine for me.

So what's the problem with my default browser (IE8, Flock2.6)?  Any configuration setting or what?

Comment: Can you provide details of the full exception you are receiving. This should hopefully tell exaclt the issue with the VS.NET runtime that is hosting your ASP.NET application. And you are running it through VS.NET and not IIS correct?

Comment: VS hasn't any internal web browser, it has internal web server. Your site is opened in default web browser. If you set up web application in IIS then usually you need to set right user as sql server won't allow to use databases to ASP.NET user by default.

Comment: I don't receive any exception from VS.NET. And I am running directly through VS 2008. ASP.NET development server runs perfectly when I start run button but my default browser don't show the page. Default browser shows connection error.

Comment: And secondly I don't add any database to my website. I just simply create new website and select location as file system & language as C#. And add one label control and one button. when button is clicked, the text "hello world" shows in a label. It is simply a hello world application. But when I run the application any browser in my PC don't show the page. And VS has internal browser, I opened my page with internal browser. I clicked on file menu and select  browse with option & then select internal browser. My page works fine with internal browser. It shows hello world when I clicked button

Comment: Tell me What can I do to fix this error.

Comment: Can you give more details of the error?

Comment: When I clicked run button in VS 2008. The message pops up "ASP.NET development server" & default browser opens automatically, IE8(my default browser) shows "The page cannot be displayed" error. Actually it can't find the address. For exmaple "http://localhost:49707/Website1/Default.aspx"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem; it was my antivirus. Here is the solution If you use nod32:

Follow these steps to solve this issue:

1. Double-click on Nod32 icon on tray and Open it up.
2. If it is not in "Advanced Mode" , switch to Advanced Mode. ( you can do it by clicking on the bottom-left link "Display:Standard Mode" and then click on "Toggle Advanced Mode")
3. Then goto SETUP section. then on the Right Pane click on "Antivirus and Antispyware protection". The panel should be opened.
4. Now in the "Web Access protection" click on "Configure..."
5. From the left Tree go to path : "Web access protection > HTTP > Web Browsers"
6. Now you should see visual studio 8 "devenv.exe" in the list.
7. Click on it twice till you see a cross sign in the box. ( Note on CROSS sign , not mark sign !)
8. with this cross sign you tell the Nod32 that this program should not be scanned and filtered for web access.

These steps solved my problem and now I can access my page from `localhost:<portNumber>`.